# Ember.js always loads index route

Tags: ember.js

I have a very simple set up, 2 routes.

1-index
2-classes

My issue is no matter what url I navigate to, the index route is loaded

Here is my js code

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#ember123'
});
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    initFoundation: function() {
        Ember.$(document).foundation();
    }.on('didInsertElement')
});
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.route('classes', {path:'class'});
    this.route('index', {path:'/'});

});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Ember.$.getJSON('url').then(function(classData) {
            return classData;
        });
    }
});
```

Any my html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{outlet}}
</script> 

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="classes">
    //some html
</script> 

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    //some html
</script>
```

Even if i navigate to "/class" I get the html in index.

Comment: Does this work? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qedutayequ/1/

Comment: Yes, could there be an issue with my setup? This is basically all my js on the page. I don't see how any of it could be conflicting. You can see the page up and running at http://stnaclassesincolumbus.com  the content should change when you go to http://stnaclassesincolumbus.com/class

Comment: http://stnaclassesincolumbus.com/#/class works

Comment: wait, why do i need the '/#/'

Comment: How are you doing your Ember development? Are you using Ember CLI? Have you checked if this happens only in your server or also locally?

Comment: No I am using plain coda off of a FTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your application is configured to use the browser's hash to navigate around your site, hence the `/#/` that needs to be in the url.  You can disable this behavior with this block of code and then `/class` should work:

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'auto'
});
```

This uses [AutoLocation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.AutoLocation.html) to select the best option based on a user's browser.

Comment: Quick follow-up if this changes, how should I generate the hard coded links to my pages, with or without the hash?

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to handle that unfortunately